# Can I export a excel with a beautiful format by using PHP?

Tags: php, export-to-excel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Format text in Excel file via PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279917/format-text-in-excel-file-via-php)

My boss wants me to build a program that can generate and export a beautiful and colorful excel file. Is there any way for me to do this? Any specific library?

Comment: What is your specific question? This is like asking, "How do I create a beautiful and colorful painting of my subject?"

Comment: A similar question has already been posed and answered: [Format text in Excel file via PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279917/format-text-in-excel-file-via-php). Please use the search function next time. See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Answer (score 1):

You could check out [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) and see if that will work for you. Look under the features tab for it on the page. It seems to be able to do any formatting stuff you might need.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a PHP guy but take a look at [this](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) and see if this suits your needs.